# Subsonic abp on .net Kentico project

Tags: asp.net, subsonic, kentico

I'm working on a Kentico website and am trying to add Subsonic 2.X to it. I've followed the instructions here:

[Link to SS setup](http://geekswithblogs.net/scottkuhl/archive/2006/11/17/97470.aspx)

When I try to build it I'm getting an error that it can't find a namespace, the namespace it can't find is the one I've set it in the web.config to generate. My web.config looks fine, I've got the ABP file in place and rebuilding etc. makes no difference. It's like SS is not generating the classes for the DB but I can't figure out why.

Some more info, I don't want to use Subsonic with this project but I'm inheriting older code (Kentico v5) and it has subsonic usage throughout it. As I'm using portions of this code I need to add subsonic to this version (7) of Kentico but am getting nowhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not really solving your direct problem, but I've always had more luck with pre-generating the classes as actual files with sonic.exe. Seems a lot less "magic" and the sonic utility gives you a little bit of feedback along the lines of "Oh yeh, I forgot to add a primary key to some random lookup table"

Comment: I agree, I much prefer the pre-generation of classes as well but for whatever reason this project refused to cooperate with either solution. So I've ended up retro fitting LINQ to remove the SS code.